# Angular and .net core application hosing in nginx

Tags: .net, angular, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

We have create an Angular + .net core applicaiton using the template in visual studio.
This has been built and publihed in fasthosts under nginx.

browings to https://www.example.com works perfectly. Application calling /weatherforecast works perfectly.

Browing directly to https://www.example.com/internalLink fails - This is because this route doesnt not physically exist.

to fix this, we have to put in :-

```
location ~ ^/ {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

into the nginx config.
Having this we can now navigate directly to the inner page,  however because of having this,  when the application calls

```
/weatherforcast,
```

this now fails. (removing it and the api call works again)

Is there a way for location to IGNORE the request to weatherforcast?